# How to silence fx cop warning CS0067?

Tags: code-analysis, fxcop

On a build server, I see some weird message. It doesn't say so, but I think it's from some software called 'fx cop'

> Warning CS0067: The event 'SunGard.Adaptiv.AnalyticsEngine.UI.CommonControls.DisabledCommand.CanExecuteChanged' is never used

How can I silence this message? Without changing what my class does.

```
sealed class DisabledCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
```

I stumbled upon docs for [`System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx) which sounds useful, but there aren't any examples for my warning.

Comment: Why don't you use the event or get rid of it?

Comment: @RyanGates: It's from an interface.

Comment: Just so you know, an error code starting with "CS" is from the C# compiler, not FxCop.  An FxCop warning or error will start with "CA" (for "code analysis").

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need to create an event that is never raised, you should make a noop event:

```
public EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
    add { }
    remove { }
}
```

The compiler is complaining because a default ("field-like") event will create a hidden backing field to store the handlers.   Since you never raise the event, that field just wastes memory.

Comment: I would consider to implement the event using *explicit interface implementation*, so the event is hidden when the actual implementation type is used directly.

Comment: @RamondeKlein I tried that, but it didn't make the warning go away.

Comment: Also consider putting `throw NotSupportedException();` inside both the `add` accessor and the `remove` accessor. Plus @RamondeKlein's suggestion. So a full solution could be `EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged { add { throw NotSupportedException(); } remove { throw NotSupportedException(); } }`